# Get current fragment from ActionBar tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have two fragments (Fragment1 and Fragment2), created ActionBar navigation with custom TabListener Class. Each tab's contant is one of my fragments. But now I have a problem - I can't access / get fragment's instances.

```
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {   
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode( getSupportActionBar().NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS );

        Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab()
            .setText( R.string.frag1 )
            .setTabListener( 
                new MyTabListener( this, 
                    Fragment1.class.getName() ) );
        getSupportActionBar().addTab( tab );

        tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab()
            .setText( R.string.frag2 )
            .setTabListener( 
                new MyTabListener( this, 
                    Fragment2.class.getName() ) );
        getSupportActionBar().addTab( tab );

        Fragment1 f1 = (Fragment1) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAG1");
        if(f1 != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "It's not empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Photo Intent Goes Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(data != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "It's not empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  


                }  

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "It's empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private class MyTabListener  implements TabListener
    {
        private SherlockFragment mFragment;
        private final Activity mActivity;
        private final String mFragName;

        public MyTabListener( Activity activity, 
            String fragName )
        {
            mActivity = activity;
            mFragName = fragName;
        }


        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab,
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            mFragment = (SherlockFragment) SherlockFragment.instantiate( mActivity, 
                    mFragName );

            if( mFragment instanceof Fragment1 ) {
                Fragment1 f1temp = (Fragment1) mFragment;

                //Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Frag1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  ft.add( android.R.id.content, mFragment,"FRAG1");
            }

            else {
                  ft.add( android.R.id.content, mFragment,"ELSE");
            }


            //Toast.makeText(mActivity, mFragName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab,
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            ft.remove( mFragment );
            mFragment = null;

        }

        public SherlockFragment getCurrentFragment() {
            return mFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab,
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
```

I can't use  `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById( id )`, because I have no id also I have tried `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag( tag )` but it didn't work either because I only call `add()` method `FragmentTransaction` class not `replace()`

Is it any way to get current tab fragment instance so I can call fragment's methods?

Comment: Explain better what you trying to do, you have 2 fragments, So you want to know how to create methods for each Fragment class?

Comment: I want to get fragment's instance, that would allow my to call methods of that the fragment, pass some variables, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. I tried to get instance of fragment in `onActivityResult()` method and that actually worked.

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

Toast.makeText(this, "Photo Intent Goes Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(data != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "It's not empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
                   Fragment1 f1 = (Fragment1) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAG1");
                  f1.onCameraResult(requestCode,resultCode,data); // Your method   of the fragment

                }  

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "It's empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where in the code did you assign the Fragment Id (i.e. FRAG1)?

Comment: You set a Fragment's tag when you call `FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment, String)` or `FragmentTransaction.replace(int, Fragment, String)`, where the tag is the `String` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I get fragment from `FragmentPagerAdapter` instance:

```
FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = (FragmentPagerAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter();
Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition());
```